# Kafka Consumer with Consumer offSetforTimes()

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka and I am using the following consumer configuration

```
super.getPropertiesConfig().put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "Consumer_" + consumerGroupId);
        super.getPropertiesConfig().put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroupId);
        super.getPropertiesConfig().put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000");
        super.getPropertiesConfig().put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, "500");
        super.getPropertiesConfig().put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "300000");
        super.getPropertiesConfig().put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "500");
        super.getPropertiesConfig().put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        super.getPropertiesConfig().put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        super.getPropertiesConfig().put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        super.getPropertiesConfig().put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
```

and  when I start the consumer I use offsetfortimes, which I use to consume messages which are produced in a topic, based on a timestamp. But, when the consumer is started, the messages that I intend to consume are not consumed. I read in one of the Stackoverflow posts that a consumer will not be able to consume messages ,which got produced before it started , if the `auto.offset.reset` is `"latest"`, is my configuration right? Can I use offsetsForTimes along with the configuration that I am using here?

```
 kafkaConsumer = consumerHelperFactory.getConsumerInstance(consumerConfiguration);
        long duration = startTime.until(Instant.now(), MINUTES)+1;
        log.info("Consumer consuming messages {} minutes ago",duration);
        Map<TopicPartition, Long> query = new HashMap<>();
        query.put(new TopicPartition(topic, 0), Instant.now().minus(duration, MINUTES).toEpochMilli());
        Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> result = kafkaConsumer.offsetsForTimes(query);
        kafkaConsumer.assign(result.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        result.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry->{
            if(entry.getValue() !=null){
                Long offset = entry.getValue().offset();
                TopicPartition partition = entry.getKey();
                kafkaConsumer.seek(partition, offset);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you tagged it with [spring-kafka](/questions/tagged/spring-kafka) (which is for the Spring for Apache Kafka project, which you don't appear to be using), so I removed it.

Just getting the offsets from the consumer won't do anything; you will need to seek to those offsets before polling the consumer. Otherwise, the position will be set to the end (due to the `auto.offset.reset=latest`).

Comment: So, do I have to say seek after I assign the offset? What if I change auto.offset.reset to earliest?

Comment: `>assign the offset` - you mean "assign  the partition". Yes, you can only seek partitions that are assigned. If you change it to `earliest` without seeking, you will get all the records. The offset reset is irrelevant if you perform seeks on all the assigned partitions. Kafka maintains 2 pointers, position and committed offset; they are independent except, if there is no committed offset, the initial position is base on the offset reset. If you commit the offset, the next time the consumer starts, it will begin at that offset (unless you again perform seeks).

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer, I have modified the question based on your comments, please let me know if my logic would work.

Comment: Also, one more question, if I start the consumer with this configuration, my consumer still will consume messages which were produced after it started right?

Comment: Yes, as long as you keep polling, until you close it.